# ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED graphql-file upload with nodejs is not working

Tags: node.js, apollo-server, graphql-js, graphql-upload

I'm trying to create a graphql api to upload files using nodejs. I use graphql-upload package to upload the file but it doesn't work. I'm getting 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED' Error. I tried so many solutions but nothing worked.

This is the code I wrote.

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');
const { GraphQLUpload } = require('graphql-upload');
const fs = require('fs');

const typeDefs = gql`
  scalar Upload

  type File {
    filename: String!
    mimetype: String!
    encoding: String!
  }

  type Query {
    hello: String!
  }

  type Mutation {
    singleUpload(file: Upload!): File!
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Upload: GraphQLUpload,
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello, GraphQL!',
  },
  Mutation: {
    singleUpload: async (_, { file }) => {
      const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file;
      // Modify the file path where you want to save the uploaded file
      const filePath = `./uploads/${filename}`;
      const stream = createReadStream();
      const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

      await stream.pipe(writeStream);

      return { filename, mimetype, encoding };
    },
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

When I run the above code it results with an error.

```
D:\CRUD-APIS\graphql-file-upload>node index.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50971/33dd6fd0-e3f5-4780-9c5d-c7dd5474bdcc
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in D:\CRUD-APIS\graphql-file-upload\node_modules\graphql-upload\package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:453:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:731:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\CRUD-APIS\graphql-file-upload\index.js:2:27) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

I didn't understand what exactly happening here. If anyone knows how to upload a file using graphql with nodejs please share.

Thank you

I'm trying to write an api using graphql and nodejs to upload a file. I tried the code which I attached to this but every time I run the project Im getting

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in D:\CRUD-APIS\graphql-file-upload\node_modules\graphql-upload\package.json
```

I couldnt upload the file using this. If anyone know how to upload file using graphql and nodejs please share your answers.